# Sorting in MongoDB by elemMatch

Tags: mongodb

Is there a way of sorting in MongoDB based on an `$elemMatch`? For example, I have documents which look like this:

```
{
    'user': ObjectId('fsdfsdf'),
    ...
    'array_of_things': [
        {
            'attribute_1': ObjectId('sdfsdfsd'),
            'attribute_2': ObjectId('sdfsfsdf'),
            'value': 30000
        },
        {
            'attribute_1': ObjectId('dfdfgfdg'),
            'attribute_2': ObjectId('gdfgdfgd'),
            'value': 100
        },
        {
            'attribute_1': ObjectId('mbnmbbmb'),
            'attribute_2': ObjectId('mbnmbnmb'),
            'value': 2000
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

I need to be able to query this data based on a matching element inside the `array_of_things` field (which is simple enough with an `$elemMatch`).  The problem arises because I also need to be able to sort by value (ascending or descending) that match a certain attribute. For example, a query might be:

```
{
    'user': ObjectId('fsdfsdf'),
    'array_of_things': {
        $elemMatch: {
            'attribute_1': ObjectId('dfdfgfdg'),
            'value': {
                $gt: 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sorting solely on `value` (e.g. `sort({ 'array_of_things.value': -1 })` predictably only sorts on all values in any array element, not matching `attribute_1` first.

Is there a way to do this?

Apologies if this is an already-asked question, but I can't seem to find any solution to it after looking.

Comment: I believe you wish to get this out via $unwind and the $sort on the value field you pick out using the aggregation framework, I think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is currently not possible with the standard query language. You can achieve it with the aggregation framework at (potentially) some performance penalty.

Comment: Ah, that's what I was afraid of